# Why do our requests take a long time to return?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

We are using ASP.NET 3 and .NET 4 - and a few different IISes (7, 8 and Express versions).

All requests to the server take a **long** time to return, in the order of around 10 seconds, no matter what's being requested. We can see (by attaching the debugger) that controller methods are being called immediately and returning quickly (within milliseconds).

We can also see that when the GET completes, the browser finishes rendering etc. quickly (within milliseconds). So the delay is between e.g. 'return View(whatever)' and the GET completing. This suggests to me something like View compilation - but it happens on every request, so shouldn't a View be compiled after the first request?

We could use View precompilation but unfortunately enabling it causes many errors and we don't really want to have to rebuild the entire web project in an effort to make it work. As I said above, a View should be compiled on first use, so precompilation should only help on the first request that uses a particular View.

Any idea how to diagnose this and find out what's actually taking the time?

---

Edit: After taking out one of the Partial Views that is rendered on every page, suddenly everything is faster. Investigating that View now.

Comment: Have you used a .net profiler tool?

Comment: If you fire up IE and hit F12 and go to the networking tab, how long does it show for each request there?

Comment: Have you looked at a client network profile? Chrome has a nice tool, hit F12, click "Network" and load the page and see what's taking so long.

Comment: @Nate beat me to it :-)

Comment: What's in your views? If the page is large, or if there's a lot of code to execute, or if there's a lot of Javascript to run on `.ready()`, or you're pulling in extra stuff from CDNs that's not being cached for long (or at all), then all of these can result in slow load times.

Comment: is it possible that somebody used a whole page updatepanel with lots of gridviews etc. and no Asnyc method ?

Comment: you can try to use http://getglimpse.com/ to check what is going on server

Comment: Do you use session-state? Caching? Have you tried attaching tools like mini-profiler? Looked at the size of the http response? Looked at when scripts run?

Comment: @outcoldman Glimpse is pretty awesome, agreed

Comment: Please install http://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/ using Nuget. It should clear up some issues.

Comment: If the page you're working on is executing a large number of ajax requests then this could cause the slowdown because no concurrent access to the session state is allowed. You can read more about this here:

http://blog.whiletrue.com/2010/09/asp-net-mvc-sessions-and-concurrent-requests-not-what-youd-expect/

In any case placing [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] attribute on to your controller will resolve this issue assuming you are not relying on the session in your code.

Comment: How about static files, or just mvc pages are slow? Are you sure there is no external scripts holding your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit code looks like this:

```
itemFactory.Add()
    .Text(menuItem.Caption)
    .Selected(menuItem.Selected)
    .Action(menuItem.Action, menuItem.Controller)
    .Enabled(menuItem.Enabled)
    .Visible(menuItem.Visible)
    ;
```

This C# code is building a Telerik PanelBar (menu). The various methods of this 'fluent interface' are setting properties on the item that's being added.

Unfortunately, one method doesn't do as you might expect: Action(actionName, controllerName).

Rather than setting the controller action to be executed when the PanelBar item is clicked, calling this method actually executes the action on the controller.

It seems this is done asynchronously, however, as tracing the above code showed that it ran almost instantly and therefore it was ruled out.

The fix is to use the Url method, not the Action method, and build the Url using the ASP.NET MVC Url method. This is rather counter-intuitive, as the Telerik ASP.NET MVC framework surely should work with MVC first and URLs second, but we should have:

1. Consulted the documentation rather than assuming what methods did
2. Noticed that the app suddenly became slower by a large, fixed
   amount, on each page load

I had been clueless after running a profiler, because it seemed that controller methods were being called that I didn't expect - and the origin of the calls seemed to be from Telerik's code (not ours). It was only when I removed the pieces of the Navigation partial view one at a time that I eventually discovered what Action() was doing.

Asynchronous code is great, except when you try to debug/profile and can't find where it's called from!

Thanks for the suggestions in the comments.